# Intermittent stack overflow errors with groovy jsonBuilder in Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am getting intermittent stack overflow errors using the groovy jsonBuilder with the groovy post build plugin in Jenkins.  I'd say that the code below works about 25% of the time and the other 75% fails.  Any ideas what could be causing this?  First part of the error is below. Thank you.

```
import groovy.json.*
import hudson.model.*


def projectName = manager.build.project.name
def job = manager.hudson.instance.getItem(projectName)
def scm = job.scm
def rtcStream = scm.getStreamName()
def rtcWorkspace = scm.getWorkspaceName()
def duration = manager.build.getExecutor().getElapsedTime()
def result = manager.build.result

def json = new JsonBuilder()

def root = json.build {
    build_number manager.build.number
    build_timestamp manager.build.timestamp
    build_duration duration
    build_url manager.build.url
    build_project_name projectName
    stream rtcStream
    workspace rtcWorkspace
    build_culprits manager.build.culprits
    build_result result.toString()
}

def jsonString = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString())
manager.listener.logger.println jsonString

def channel = manager.build.workspace.channel;

def fp = new hudson.FilePath(channel, manager.build.workspace.toString() + "\\build.json")

if(fp != null) {
    manager.listener.logger.println "Getting ready to write build.json"
    fp.write(jsonString, null); //writing to file
    manager.listener.logger.println "Done writing build.json"
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL: null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5636.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3653)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2379)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2396)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$83.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:146)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:138)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson$3.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:50)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson$4.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$_toJson_closure2.doCall(JsonOutput.groovy:150)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5636.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3653)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2379)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2396)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$83.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:146)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:138)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson$3.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:50)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson$4.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$_toJson_closure2.doCall(JsonOutput.groovy:150)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5636.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3653)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2379)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2396)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$83.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:146)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:138)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson$3.callStatic(Unknown Source)
```

Output of the elements:

```
build num: 25
timestamp: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1389797077000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="US/Eastern",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=US/Eastern,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=3,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=15,DAY_OF_YEAR=15,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=44,SECOND=37,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]
duration: 317805
url: job/Client_March_Report/25/
project: Client_March_Report
stream: Stream_Client_Development
workspace: Jenkins_Client_Workspace
culprits: []
result: FAILURE
```

Comment: Sounds like one of your elements contains itself...  Can you log the inputs, and see which one is causing the crash?

Comment: Try changing `manager.build.timestamp` to `manager.build.timestamp.toString()`

Comment: Of course I haven't been able to get it to fail.  Adding the toString() to the timestamp gives me this in the JSON output:

"build_timestamp": "java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1389797077000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"US/Eastern\",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=US/Eastern,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1, ...

Comment: Yeah, I went through those params, and I believe that's the only one that's a complex object...  Maybe `manager.build.timestampString` is [a better choice](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getTimestampString())?

Comment: It looks like timestampString is really build duration in minutes.  For example: timestamp: 18 min.  I'll keep at this - I think you are right that this is due to the timestamp object.  Going to try timestampString2

Comment: Or try:  `manager.build.timestamp.format( 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss' )`

Comment: It looks like timestampString2 will work for me.  Thank you for all of your help - if you want to post this as an answer I'll give it the thumbs up.

Comment: That's even better!  Thanks again.

Comment: Added as an answer, no worries, glad we got to the bottom of it!  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually caused by a complex object having a internal reference to itself, which causes the json builder to infinitely loop.

Looking at all the variables in the `json.build`, the only complex one I can see is the `manager.build.timestamp` (which is a `Calendar` instance)

You can try one of these alternatives:

```
build_timestamp manager.build.timestampString // get duration of build
```

or

```
build_timestamp manager.build.timestampString2 // Not sure
```

or indeed,

```
build_timestamp manager.build.timestamp.format( 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss' )
```

To format the calendar to a Date/Time String

Fingers crossed!